# Jquery Carousel - calculations if active slide is not one with specific ID then to slide to it.

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

The question isn't massively helpful I suppose so I'll try to be as clear as I can.

So I have a setup where my header has 4 anchor texts in them. The First part of the body has a custom jquery carousel in it.

What I'm trying to acheive is basically make it so that when any of the four anchor links in the header are clicked they scroll to a specific slide which I have given an ID. The issue I have of course is allowing for the carousel to have any slide active and having the anchor links calculate which slide is active and how much it needs to slide to get to the correct slide.

Here is the jquery for the carousel:

```
var carousel;            // used as the object for the carousel
var carousels = [];      // will hold any and all carousels on the page
var preventTimeouts = false;
var intervals = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
carousels.push(new carousel('slideshow_window', 'slidesHolder', '.slide', 920, 10000, 1000, true));  
});

carousel = function CarouselSlider(windowName, slideCollectionWrapper,slideCollection, slideWidth, slideChangeInterval, slideChangeSpeed, requireNavButtons) {

// Variables

var slideWidth = slideWidth;                        // the width of each slide
var slides_array = $(slideCollection).toArray();
var numberOfSlides = slides_array.length;
var slideChangeInterval = slideChangeInterval;      // how often the slides will automatically change
var slideChangeSpeed = slideChangeSpeed;            // how fast the slides change
var slideIntervalId;                                // holds the interval event (the event for the next time that the slides should change)
var animating = false;                              // used to track whether an animation is underway
var currentPosition = 0;                            // used to highlight the centre image to begin with
var requireNavButtons = requireNavButtons;

var windowName = windowName;
var collectionWrapper = slideCollectionWrapper;

// Carousel

$('#' + windowName).append("<div id=\"" + collectionWrapper + "\"></div>"); // set up the collection wrapper
$('#' + collectionWrapper).css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
$('#' + collectionWrapper).css('position', "relative");

for (var i = 0; i < slides_array.length; i++)               // add items from the collection to the wrapper
    $('#' + collectionWrapper).append(slides_array[i]);
$('#' + collectionWrapper).css('left', 920 - slideWidth);

//    for (i = 0; i < slides_array.length; i++) {                 // run one  round of the carousel to ensure correct positioning
//        currentposition++;
//        moveslide(true, true);                                  // set 'forced' to true to disable the animation
//    }
function changePosition(forwards) {
    forwards ? currentPosition++ : currentPosition--;
    moveSlide(forwards, false);
}

function moveSlide(forwards, forced) {
    var nextSlide;
    animating = true;

    if (forwards) {
        nextSlide = currentPosition % numberOfSlides;
        var t_dur = forced ? 0 : slideChangeSpeed;
        $('#' + collectionWrapper).append(slides_array[nextSlide]);
        $('#' + collectionWrapper).append(slides_array[nextSlide + 1 > numberOfSlides - 1 ? 0 : nextSlide + 1]); // load the next two slides
        $('#' + collectionWrapper)
              .animate({ left: "-=" + slideWidth, queue: false },
               t_dur,
               function () {
                   $('#' + collectionWrapper + ' ' + slideCollection + ':first').remove();
                   $('#' + collectionWrapper).css('left', 0);
                   animating = false;
               });
    }
    else {
        nextSlide = (currentPosition % numberOfSlides);
        $('#' + collectionWrapper).prepend(slides_array[nextSlide - 1 < 0 ? numberOfSlides + nextSlide : nextSlide]);
        $('#' + collectionWrapper).prepend(slides_array[nextSlide < 0 ? numberOfSlides + nextSlide : nextSlide]);
        $('#' + collectionWrapper).css('left', 0 - slideWidth); // increase offset to account for prepended slides
        $('#' + collectionWrapper)
            .animate({ left: "+=" + slideWidth, queue: false },
            slideChangeSpeed,
            function () {
                $('#' + collectionWrapper + ' ' + slideCollection + ':last').remove();
                animating = false;
            });
    }
}

/*
Navigation buttons
*/

$("#next").click(function () {
    if (!animating) {                                                       // only queue one click at a time
        changePosition(true);
    }
});
$("#prev").click(function () {
    if (!animating) {
        changePosition(false);
    }
});
$("#prevSearch").click(function () {
    if (!animating) {
        changePosition(false);
    }
});
$("#prevSearch2").click(function () {
    $("#modalContainer").hide();
    if (!animating) {
        changePosition(false);
    }

});
```

}